# Django Rest Framework HTTP Post Calls and Authentication with Ionic Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, curl, ionic-framework

I implemented the Django Rest Framework into my Django project so I could use Django as a backend to my Ionic Framework app while maintaining the web app that I can make with Django. I went through the process to OAuth2, using the oauth toolkit, but now I am unsure on how to make the http request calls from the ionic framework side to authenticate a user and get a token. So far on the Ionic side I have the http request as:

```
login(username, password, url) {
    let headers = new Headers()
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return this.http.post(url,
      {"username": username,
        "password": password,
      }, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

But when I run it in my browser, I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

On the server side the curl command `curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD" -u "CLIENT ID:CLIENT SECRET" https://www.example.com/o/token/` works perfectly fine and returns a token, where USERNAME, PASSWORD, CLIENT ID, and CLIENT SECRET are all the respective values.

I'm not sure if this is the right question, but how do I turn the cURL command into something I can use in my Ionic app?

These are my Rest Framework and CORS Settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ]
}

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'localhost:8100',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: Take a look to: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: I currently have that installed already and the whitelist includes "localhost:8100"

Comment: Mmm if you're sure it's well installed (present in middleware, right settings), don't know..

Comment: I edited the question to include my rest framework and cors settings that are in my settings.py. Are these settings correct?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that if you are sending requests with the origin being `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, which is the same thing, most browsers send the origin as `Null`, so it is better to add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to the `settings.py` file of the main Django project.

Once that was there, I was getting errors about the `grant_type` being invalid, so in my request I had to add `"grant_type": "password"`, and I also had to add `"client_id": <your client id here>` where the `<your client id here>` is your client id without the `<>`.

I also found that Postman is a great application to help with api creation and translating cURL commands into HTTP requests that work.